# How do I modify the url of uploaded media content?

Tags: uploads, media

I have just moved hosts, and with the move I've also changed the setup that I have for media uploads.

I used to host my media on a subdomain called media.detailsofmylife.net, but now that I have switched over, I want to go back to the traditional detailsofmylife.net/wp-content/uploads/ style. I have already backed up and relocated the content so it should be ready to go.

For example, yesterday, an image used to located here:

http://media.detailsofmylife.net/uploads/2013/06/Cyril-Hahn-Perfect-Form.jpg

but now it is located here:

http://www.detailsofmylife.net/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/Cyril-Hahn-Perfect-Form.jpg

Could someone please help me with the necessary SQL statement to correct all of the old url references to the new format?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a plugin like [Deploy Helper](http://wordpress.org/plugins/deploy-helper/). Essentially, it allows you to swap out all instances of one URL with another, and will also handle serialized data.

Just enter the old URL as `media.detailsofmylife.net/uploads` and the new one as `www.detailsofmylife.net/wp-content/uploads`.

Make sure you also reset your custom upload paths. If you'd defined constants like `WP_CONTENT_URL` or `UPLOADS` in your `wp-config.php`, remove them. Similarly, delete any possible settings in the database by loading `wp-admin/options.php` in your browser & emptying the values for `upload_path` & `upload_url_path`.